# Desktop/iPad/iPhone PSD frames for screenshots workflow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, user-experience

In the past, I've googled iPhone user interface elements and downloaded the PSD.
2. I deleted all layers except the frame
3. I took screenshots of my various web projects
4. Change dimensions and inserted various screenshots from other emulators or iPhone to show up in portfolio.

Maybe this is the "right way", although it is time-consuming and the pain the butt. It's not a problem, for it is easy enough to do just tedious. Has anyone found a simple workflow for this process? I feel like there's probably some tool out there that asked for screenshots and automatically exports PNG's for portfolios. Maybe I'm wrong.

Any tools or workflow recommendations?

Comment: Note that everyone knows what an iPhone already looks like. There's really no reason to add it to your mock-up. Show the screens. That's all the people that are interested in hiring you are interested in.

Comment: I know that but it is aesthetically pleasing to display designs in a frame. Look at any famous artist or even semi famous, their work is complemented by frames. Presentation matters.

Comment: True, but Picasso isn't famous because of his choice of frames. :) And as a hiring manager, while I may appreciate the time you took into mockup up a fake iPhone screen, I'm really more interested in what you put in the actually screen. I, personally, don't need the extra 'frame' no matter how nice it is. (That said, I'm on the assumption this is a portfolio for showing your work to employers. If you're talking about a portfolio for clients, having the nice 'frames' is probably a fine idea.)

Comment: Exactly – it's not for employers. It is for clients.  You didn't know the Picassos frames had all the power; each frame has liquid Tourmaline and rubies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this post from abduzeedo.com very helpful.  http://abduzeedo.com/useful-design-mockups-your-portfolio  some of the mockups even have a duplicated smart object right in the first layer.  All you have to do is replace the content in that smart object and you're good to go.

Comment: This is the efficient answer. However, the answer below is the more creative and exploratory solution.

Answer (score 2):

I do like the link Julian has posted but the issue with using opensource mock-ups is eventually it feels like everyone has them.  If you want to be creative why not make your own?

It would appear that you are virtually down that route but I think you are not executing your workflow effectively.  I say that because you have not stated anything about implementing smart objects per your question.  If you have cut everything out and setup the document to your desired look why not create the layer you are applying the design as a smart object so you can edit it later on and you will have the option to reuse it?

Another option I enjoy is buying photos from stock photo sites like this one

[image]

and designing apps and placing them in the phone via smart object.  Granted it does take some work but afterwards its unique and another mockup I could sell.

If you dont know how to use smart objects you could check out some videos from AdobeTV:

1. [AdobeTV search for Smart Objects.](http://tv.adobe.com/search/?q=smart%20objects&product_id=&topic_id=&release_id=&t_lid=)
2. [Transforming Smart Objects](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/understanding-adobe-photoshop-cs6/transforming-smart-objects/)
3. [Modifying a vector Smart Object in Illustrator](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cc/modifying-a-vector-smart-object-in-illustrator/)
4. [Importing vector art as a Smart Object](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cc/importing-vector-art-as-a-smart-object/)

Comment: Great advice. I have only used smart objects with different icons to change color, shift size etc. thanks for expanding my mind.

Comment: I like this idea as well.  Using your own graphic makes your work stand out from others especially in a presentation